# How long exposure to microwave radiation is considered dangerous?

Tags: radiation, microwaves

Today I wanted to heat my breakfast in the microwave, when the microwave finished heating my food I pressed the button to open the door, but at that moment the microwave turned again, with the door a little open, then stopped when I opened completely the door. All this happened in a span of 1.5 ~ seconds. I know the exposure was short, but I really want to know if I'm in any danger.